# Is there a term that describes an application that gets smarter the more data it has?

Tags: terminology

A coworker of mine has asked me for a term (preferably an adjective) that can be used to describe a system that gets more "intelligent" as it gets more data. The example she used when asking me this question was "as Google crawls more sites, it gets smarter at searching".

Personally, the best I could think of offhand was "adaptive", but that doesn't feel right. Can anyone suggest something better?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's called SkyNet?

Comment: Maybe Arnie is going to come back and kill Jeff to prevent SO from ever existing and abeger from getting his answer ;-)

Comment: Google isn't really a good example here, as Google's engineers have to constantly intervene to keep the application from returning incorrect results.  By manually intervene, I mean manually remove certain sites from the listings, change the Page Rank algorithm, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you refer to things like spam filters as "trainable". Perhaps that could apply here.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a vague description of an [expert system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system), which often have a learning aspect and use it to gain more "expertise" in their problem domain.

Comment: Most people under the age of 30 have probably never even *heard* of an expert system :-)

Comment: I'm 22 and I've heard stories about expert systems. Primarily how they attempted to rise and control humanity by sending an Austrian with a shotgun back in time to kill some woman.

Comment: But, AFAIK, an expert system does not, by definition, involve learning.

Comment: @Kena no, it does not, but they are often referred to that way.

Answer (score 2):

The domain of this kind of applications is "machine-learning". But I'm not aware of a matching adjective.

Answer (score 1):

> The example she used when asking me this question was "as Google crawls more sites, it gets smarter at searching".

Unlike learning algorithms, where the algorithm itself changes based on past success, Google searches get better due to improved ranking of the results bringing the best pages to the top. The quality of the [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) algorithm's results increases due to the network effect of the input data - the more connections, the better the chance that the best connected page is the most relevant.

The rule that says the effect of a network is super-linear is [Metcalfe's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metcalfe's_law), so if the "smartness" of an algorithm relies on network effects you could call the algorithm "Metcalfian". I've no idea whether the quality of PageRank results is super-linear in the number of inputs though; if anything I'd expect it to be sub-linear, as once you have enough links in the network to get rid of noise the rankings should be stable.

Comment: I've heard it described as a "network effect", which is basically what you describe here.

Comment: @Kevin the phrase "network effect" appears twice in my answer; that is exactly what I am describing.

Answer (score 1):

What about the term "evolve" or "evolving."

Answer (score 0):

How about "capable," or "robust."

Answer (score 0):

Learning Artificial Intelligent software.

Answer (score 0):

[Skynet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminator) or [Joshua/W.O.P.R.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOPR)

Comment: That was my first thought when I saw this question!

Answer (score 0):

I would call it Heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a communications network, then it follows [Metcalfe's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metcalfe's_law). You could call it *Metcalfian*. (You'd like be laughed at.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the term is adaptive associative memory systems (leading to autonomy, perhaps).